# Getting incorrect import errors using ALE linter for Haskell files

Tags: haskell, vim

I am using [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) to lint my Haskell files in vim. ALE detects an import error for any package that did not come with the Haskell platform. I am still able to run `cabal repl` and have these packages imported properly. I then am able to load the files that have the errors into the repl which proves to me that I have indeed taken the proper steps for using these packages.

Within the files I am given proper feedback when using functions from these packages. I have of course specified these imports in the build-depends portion my `.cabal` file.

It is very annoying having my error messages clogged up with unrecognized imports.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/nBcci58W) is a copy of notable lines in my `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is one of the linters is not aware of cabal. The issue is well documented [here](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/issues/341). When you use ALE and do not specify which linters you want to use, ALE goes ahead and uses all of them.

Here is a list of the linters that ALE automatically gives you for Haskell files: `[cabal_ghc, ghc, ghc_mod, hdevtools, hie, hlint, stack_build, stack_ghc]`

The problematic linter in this case is `ghc`. To fix the error go ahead and add this line to your .vimrc file:

```
let g:ale_linters = {'haskell': ['cabal_ghc', 'ghc-mod', 'hdevtools', 'hie', 'hlint', 'stack_build', 'stack_ghc']}
```

You can use whatever linters you like from this list.